# get category name from category id in different table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables.

One table is animals. Second table is animal_details.

I am printing animals to table with loop.

```
Animals table:
id: 1
name: Dog

Animal Details table:
id: 1
name: Lorem ipsum
description: lorem ipsum dolor
animal: 1
```

I just want when i print details, i want echo animal with name (animal coming with id).
I can do this with using second query in the loop but i want to do this without using query in loop. Thanks!

Comment: ....`SELECT animal_details.description,animal_details.name
FROM animals
INNER JOIN animal_details ON animals.id = animal_details.animal;`

Comment: i did exactly same thing but it is giving me just animal_details's name. animal name does not coming..

Comment: @cihan....Okay then do a small change.`SELECT animal_details.description,animals.name,animal_details.name FROM animals INNER JOIN animal_details ON animals.id = animal_details.animal;`

Comment: @Cihan..As you have name field in both the tables but you have stored name of the animal in animals(table1) table.

Comment: animal detail name is a different thing. not animal's name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple use inner join

```
SELECT animal_details.description,animal.name,animal_details.name as detailsname
FROM animals INNER JOIN animal_details ON animals.id = animal_details.animal
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have just one match row for each animal, in animal details table better to do this:

`select * from animals, animalDetails where animal.id = animalDetails.animal`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a join query

SELECT `animals`.*, `animal_details`.*
FROM `animals`, `animal_details` where animals.id=animal_details.animal;